# Solr minimum match (mm) ignored by mandatory clause?

Tags: solr, lucene, query-parser

Solr properties:

- **solr-5.2.1**
- default operator is **AND**

I am using next query:

```
NAME:marie SECOND_NAME:curie +PROFESSION:physicist
mm=80%
```

according to [minimum match docs](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/util/doc-files/min-should-match.html) I expect that 2 clauses will be matched is search result ( as `(int) (3 * 0.8) = 2`).

As **PROFESSION** is required, I expect that in results I will have match on this property and at least one another - either **NAME** or **SECOND_NAME**.

In fact, I am getting all documents that match **PROFESSION:physicist** and any other values for other fields. If I delete **+** sign from request, solr returns results, that have at least 2 matches (so minimum match works fine in that case)

It looks like that adding mandatory option to request repeals minimum match condition. Could smb explain if that is expected behavior?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to rewrite little bit query using boolean conditions.

```
(PROFESSION:physicist) AND (NAME:marie OR SECOND_NAME:curie )
```

Also you should use dismax plugin to use Min/max

**Updated:**

From Solr4.0 The default value of mm is dictated by the q.op param (q.op=AND => mm=100%; q.op=OR => mm=0%).

Comment: rewriting query in that way worked fine with minimum match. Either I don't understand, how the query parser works, or there is some bug there.  

Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderMartynov I have updated my answer."From Solr4.0 The default value of mm is dictated by the q.op param (q.op=AND => mm=100%; q.op=OR => mm=0%)."

Comment: thank your for your answer, could you point me on some documentation / changelist to read more details?

Comment: @AlexanderMartynov DixMax You need to read more about DisMax plugin https://lucidworks.com/blog/2010/05/23/whats-a-dismax/  (DisMaxRequestHandler )

Comment: @AlexanderMartynov as you're using DisMaxHander plugin, default operator  OR is working little bit differently instead of simple query plugin.mm is always changing. => (The default value of mm is dictated by the q.op param (q.op=AND => mm=100%; q.op=OR => mm=0%).)

Comment: @AlexanderMartynov I would recommend you to use Boolean queries :)

Comment: the reason why I tried not to use booleans, is that article from [lucidworks](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2011/12/28/why-not-and-or-and-not)  :)
Also, I am a bit confused - from DisMax official documentation, I see that q.op dictates mm value [only IF NO mm is set in a querry](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser)